# OpenApi Validations

Tags: spring-boot, openapi

I have this property defined in an openapi contract

pageNumber:
type: integer
minimum: 0

When I enter invalid data like -1 , in my spring boot 2.X application it used to show message
**"pageNumber: must be greater than or equal to 0"**
Now after I have migrated to Spring boot 3, the error message changed to:
**"getEvents.arg6: must be greater than or equal to 0"**

Do you know what I could be missing ? My hunch is that previous message should be supported as it is better and if I upgrade  good things should not be missed

This is the configuration I use:

```html
apply from: "$rootDir/gradle/openapi-tools/base.gradle"

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api'
    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.2.0'
}

openApiGenerate {
    generatorName = 'spring'
    configOptions = [
            openApiNullable: "false",
            delegatePattern: "true",
            documentationProvider: "springdoc",
            configPackage: "${group}.${name}.generated.config",
            useSpringBoot3: "true"
    ]
}
```